# Rspec keeps using development database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have different databases for development and for test in `database.yml`.

I have `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'` in start of both files `rails_helper.rb` and `spec_helper.rb`, generated with rspec initialisation command.

Also, I tried `Rails.env = 'test'` without success.

I run rspec as `RAILS_ENV=test rake spec`

I don't have `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` setting or `Rails.env` setting anywhere in initialisation scripts.

However, Rspec keeps using development database instead of testing one.

I have checked a lot of similar questions around the internet and no answer helped.

Any solutions?

Comment: Have you done this `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` ? and try this one `run rake db:test:prepare` and let me know if it solve your problem.

Comment: rake db:test:prepare seems to do the job, take a look at the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of rails are you using? Try rake db:test:prepare. In Rails 4+, It's deprecated but still works. It seems like in rails 4.1+, migrations are automatically checked for, and running db:schema:load will do the trick.

Comment: `rake db:test:prepare` done the job, and now I have writes in my test DB. However, it is really strange, as I had test DB migrated already (or at least initialised as saw necessary for my application tables there). I'm still being afraid about this approach as I have bunch of another developers who might run tests and forget `rake db:test:prepare`, and their dev databases will be truncated (I'm about to use db cleaner).

I wonder if there's more robust solution.

Comment: And yes, to your questions: It's Rails 4.1+ (4.2.1)